# VS code selecting all code by default in Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I don't know how but all the text in a file seems to be highlighted in blue (as if it's selected) even when nothing is being selected in VS Code. This is pretty annoying and it goes away only when a particular part is actually selected by me. Attaching the 2 pictures below. Why is this happening and what's the fix for this?

The first picture is the one with the issue. Could this be because of some extension?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have the code, as well as the extensions to investigate, so why someone over the internet can do it better? Disable the extensions one by one and not long you know the culprit.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: @starball thank you very much, I figured out the solution because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by starball in comments, this issue was caused by the extension `SQLTools`. I used Extension bisect tool in VSCode to debug and I created an issue for the same.

Comment: add a link to your issue ticket please.